# Shorten a tableView and slide a view in below it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, uiview

Basically on the click of a cell, I want the table to animate up (shortening it's height) and a 'detail' view to slide up taking up the space now available..

I have the tableView shortening properly, but I am having problems getting the second view to slide in..

```
CGRect frame = self.tableview.frame; // (drilldown table)
if(frame.size.height > 600)
{
    CGRect detailFrame = StudyDetailView.view.frame; // (detailed view I want to slide up
    detailFrame.origin.y = (frame.size.height-200);
    self.tableview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
    StudyDetailView.view.frame = detailFrame; // <-- this does not work.
    self.tableview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,frame.size.width,frame.size.height-200); // <-- this works.

    [UIView commitAnimations];


}
```

**Update**
My fix:

### **StudyListDetailController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    self.view.frame =  CGRectMake(0,900,frame.size.width,frame.size.height);
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

In my table row select...

```
if(frame.size.height > 600)
{

    CGRect detailFrame = StudyDetailView.view.frame;

    self.tableview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    detailFrame.origin.y = (frame.size.height-200);
    detailFrame.size.height = 200;
    [self.view addSubview:StudyDetailView.view];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];

    self.tableview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,frame.size.width,frame.size.height-200);
    StudyDetailView.view.frame = detailFrame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where do you initially set `StudyDetailView.view.frame`? It looks like you've only set the Y value.
Try doing

`NSLog(NSStringFromCGRect(detailFrame));`

and see what shows up in the console, I'm guessing only the y value will be set, and the width and height are just 0.

Comment: viewdidload of detailview

    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    self.view.frame =  CGRectMake(0,900,frame.size.width,frame.size.height);

and then I tried this, but I get a bad_access error...


    self.tableview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,frame.size.width,frame.size.height-200);
    StudyDetailView.view.frame =  CGRectMake(0,frame.size.height-200,frame.size.width,frame.size.height);

Comment: You say that code is in the detailview? is that the same view as `StudyDetailView.frame`? I can't really see any reason for the error, though I do find creating the `frame` variable a little strange. Personally I'd skip out the `frame` variable and use `self.view.frame` directly.

Comment: @Critter, I have put some functions that I use to make my code involving CGRects cleaner on github (https://github.com/Jon889/JPGeneral) you may find it useful.